I want to retrieve all frames of video (mp4)
I want to extract all frames of video (mp4) that is in raw folder of my project.
val videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.video_h)

captureVideoFrames(this@OutsideCamActivity, videoUri)

I can able to get frames using the function given below, but which is slow and missing frames.
private fun captureAndDisplayFrames(videoUri: Uri) {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
            try {
                retriever.setDataSource(this@OutsideCamActivity, videoUri)

                // Get the video duration
                val videoDuration =
                    retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)?.toLong() ?: 0L

                var currentPosition = 0L
                // Capture frames at regular intervals
                while (currentPosition < videoDuration) {
                    // Extract frame at the current position
                    val frame: Bitmap? = retriever.getFrameAtTime(currentPosition * 1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC)

                    // Check if the frame was successfully retrieved
                    if (frame != null) {
                        // Update the ImageView on the main thread
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            imgOutH.setImageBitmap(frame)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("FrameExtraction", "No frame found at time: $currentPosition")
                    }

                    // Increment position (e.g., by 1 second or as per your requirement)
                    currentPosition += 1000 // Move to the next second
                }

            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Log.e("FrameExtraction", "Invalid video source: ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                Log.e("FrameExtraction", "Retriever not configured properly: ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("FrameExtraction", "Error retrieving frame: ${e.message}")
            } finally {
                retriever.release() // Always release the retriever resource
            }
        }
    }

What I did is capturing the frames and set in an ImageView.
instead of set in an ImageView my requirement is to do some processing with the image that also working fine. Issue with capturing all frames.

MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC gives you only the I-frames. But partial frames (usually the majority) are going to be missing.
You can use MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST instead to get all frames, but this is slow.
A more efficient way is to use a MediaCodec together with a MediaExtractor.
